# How to sync webcam with serial data from arduino and SR04 distance sensor

Tags: python, opencv, arduino, sensors

Ive connected my laptop with arduino+SR04 sensor. What Im trying to do is that as soon as the distance sensor detects someones presence near the laptop ( distance reading less than 50cm), I want to switch on the webcam using python-opencv (& later on save this video clip)
The problem  Im facing is that theres unsynchronized  communication between arduino+SR04 and python. The sensors reading keep popping up on the phython console for some 3-4 seconds even after the person has left (which could be due to sensor data not getting written as fast as the camera display). With such long delay, my videos will be taking up much space.

I tried increasing the delay in SR04 sensor to 500ms but thats making the webcam very choppy and slow. I dont want the video to be choppy. Please help

My arduino +SR04 code

```
const int echo_pin = 9;
const int trig_pin = 10;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(echo_pin, INPUT);
  pinMode(trig_pin, OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {
  double period, distance;
  digitalWrite(trig_pin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(trig_pin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trig_pin, LOW);
  period = pulseIn(echo_pin, HIGH);
  distance = (period / 2) / 29.1;
  //delay(500);
  Serial.println(distance);

}
```

My Python code

```
import serial
import time
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
arduino = serial.Serial('COM10', 9600)

def Measure():
    distance = arduino.readline()
    #time.sleep(.5)
    print ("distance "+str(distance)+" cm")
    return float(distance)

while True:
    output = Measure()
    if output < 50:
    
        # Capture frame-by-frame
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        # Our operations on the frame come here
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        # Display the resulting frame
        cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Can anyone please help , I'm totally stuck here

Comment: I believe OpenCV `videocapture()` buffers around 5 frames, so it will tend to capture older images than you expect. You can call `grab()` instead of `read()`  to keep the buffer empty.

Comment: @MarkSetchell tried if cap.grab(), just before cap.read, but still no luck.

Comment: It doesn't work like that. You'd have to call `cap.retrieve()`. I don't think your approach is correct. Why don't you just start a loop for 10s retrieving video inside the `if` statement? Have you tried because the size of the video file will be small even if you capture for 10s.